# How to get Windows azure to give me more useful error information

Tags: azure

I've been experimenting with the new windows azure website feature, and im getting http 500 internal server errors, but the logs are giving me very generic messages, I "think" its a problem with database connections, as everything runs fine locally. Is there some way to get more usefull error messages from azure ?

Im using C# .net 4.0 and mvc 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you adjust the custom errors section in the web.config to give you detailed errors all the time?